# Match Location Code to Name R

Tags: r, variables, dataframe

So this is a problem I can't for the life of me solve, but I imagine is relatively basic.

I have a dataframe containing events variables, one of which is FIPS10-4 region codes.  I also have a dataframe with the string name for each code.  They each look something like this:

Events

```
Date       ID     ...     FIPS10-4     ...
20130404   12345          AF01
```

FIPS10-4 Codes

```
FIPS10-4    Province
AF01        Badakhshan 
...         ...
```

I'm looking for a way to add another variable called "Province" which contains the name of the province matching the code for each event.  The final version would look like this for all of the events in the dataframe:

```
Date       ID     ...     FIPS10-4     Province    ...
20130404   12345          AF01         Badakhshan
```

Comment: You could use `merge`

Comment: ...more specifically `merge(Events, FIPS10-4Codes, by = "FIPS10-4", all.x = TRUE )`

Comment: Alternatively you can use `join` from `plyr` package. It maybe faster than `merge` and preserves the order of rows regardless of join type. See `?plyr::join` for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `merge` function. This combines two dataframes according to a common variable. [Here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html) is the documentation. As someone above noted, you can use something along the lines of `merge(my_events, fips_codes, by = "FIPS10-4", all.x = TRUE )`. Since `all.x` is true, all of the non matching cases of x are added to the result as well, with NA's filled in the corresponding columns of y. Similarly for `all.y`. Note that you can also merge `by="row.names"` if you ever need to.